# Most concise way to convert string to integer in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, number-formatting

In Java, I can convert a string to integer using two statements as follows, which is able to deal with the exception:

```
// we have some string s = "abc"
int num = 0;
try{ num = Integer.parseInt(s); } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {}
```

However, the methods I found in Scala always use the `try-catch/match-getOrElse` approach like following, which consists several lines of codes and seems a little verbose.

```
// First we have to define a method called "toInt" somewhere else
def toInt(s: String): Option[Int] = {
  try{
    Some(s.toInt)
  } catch {
    case e: NumberFormatException => None
  }
}

// Then I can do the real conversion
val num = toInt(s).getOrElse(0)
```

Is this the only way to convert string to integer in Scala (which is able to deal with exceptions) or is there a more concise way?

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/lcxjzw/safely-parsing-strings-to-numbers-in-scala ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider

```
util.Try(s.toInt).getOrElse(0)
```

This will deliver an integer value while catching possible exceptions. Thus,

```
def toInt(s: String): Int = util.Try(s.toInt).getOrElse(0)
```

or in case an `Option` is preferred,

```
def toInt(s: String): Option[Int] = util.Try(s.toInt).toOption
```

where `None` is delivered if the conversion fails.

Comment: You can drop the call to `toOption`

Comment: Sorry, I've been unclear. You can drop it for the version that does `getOrElse` (and returns an `Int`), because `Try` itself has this method. But you cannot drop for the version that returns an `Option[Int]` because a `Try` is not an `Option`.